# Change Makefile in Firebreath

Tags: c++, firebreath

The question look simple but i can't find any information on Firebreath's wiki page and on Internet.

I have my **Makefile** in my `Firebreath/build` folder. I use it to compile my plugin but in the first line it says `DO NOT EDIT`. I need to compile my plugin with a `-lcurl` flag. In my example program i use the following to compile it:

```
 g++ test.cpp -o test -lcurl
```

But, how can modify the **Makefile** or do workaround over this?

Thanks anyways.

Comment: If it says `DO NOT EDIT` it actually means `DO NOT EDIT UNLESS YOU ARE SURE WHAT YOU ARE DOING`.

Comment: Is it auto-generated from another tool?

Comment: Any idea of what should edit?

Comment: @sarnold, yes, from the command `prepmake.sh`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FireBreath uses cmake to generate the makefile or project files; if you want to add a library to link against, just edit the CMakeLists.txt file (or the [X11 or Mac or Win]/projectDef.cmake file if you want it platform specific) file and add the following line:

```
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} curl)
```

Make sure if you put it in CMakeLists.txt (the one in your project directory, not the firebreath ones!) that you make sure it's at the bottom of the file after the platform include.

Incidentally, all of this is documented [on the FireBreath website](http://www.firebreath.org/display/documentation/Using+Libraries)... search for "libraries" and you'll find it.